Given natural numbers a,b,c that satisfying the equation : $10a = 23 \phi(b)$, $10b = 23 \phi(c)$, and $10c = 23 \phi(a)$. Prove that $a=b=c$
(The title isn’t long enough)
$\phi(n)$ is denoted as the Euler Totient Function.
What have I tried:

I'm guessing this is a bounding problem.
I notice that $(a,b,c)$ is symmetric, so maybe WLOG $a \ge b \ge c$ ?
Expanding the totient function as $n(1-\frac{1}{p_1})(1-\frac{1}{p_2})..(1-\frac{1}{p_i})$, $n = \prod p_i^{r_i}$

However, from these points, I didn't make any progress. So I need a walkthrough at least. Hint or answer would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Whats the latex code for totient?

@greentea231 To get $\phi$, use \phi, else for $\varphi$, use \varphi. Note that, AFAIK, the second form is used somewhat more frequently, e.g., such as in Wikipedia's Euler's totient function article but, as stated there, both are acceptable.

We can do more than just show $a=b=c$.  We can show that they have the form $2^k11^m23^n$ for positive integers $k,m,n$.
To do this, here's the idea:

Let $p$ denote the largest prime divisor of $abc$.  Without loss of generality, you can assume $p\mid a$ and that the power of $p$ in the prime factorization of $a$ is at least as large as those powers of $b,c$.  Use contradiction to show that $p\leq 23$ and note that $23\mid a$, so that $p=23$.
Write $a = 23^n a_1$ where $23 \not\mid a_1$.  Show/note that $23\not\mid \phi(a_1)$ and use this to show that both $b,c$ can be written as $b=23^nb_1$ and $c=23^nc_1$ where $b_1,c_1$ are integers.  Using the original equations, show these values satisfy $$5a_1 = 11\phi(b_1), \qquad  5b_1=11\phi(c_1), \qquad  5c_1 = 11\phi(a_1).$$
Repeat steps 1-2 with $a,b,c$ replaced by $a_1,b_1,c_1$ and $p=11$ instead of $23$.  Show that if we define $a_2$ by $a_1=11^ma_2$ (and similarly for $b_2,c_2$), then these new values satisfy $$a_2 = 2\phi(b_2), \qquad  b_2=2\phi(c_2), \qquad  c_2 = 2\phi(a_2).$$
Repeat steps 1-2 with $p=2$ in order to conclude that we can write $a_2 = 2^k a_3$ (and similarly for $b_3,c_3$).  At this point, the equation becomes $$a_3 = \phi(b_3), \qquad b_3 = \phi(c_3), \qquad c_3 = \phi(a_3)$$ and just from $x \geq 2 \implies \phi(x) < x$, you can conclude that $a_3=b_3=c_3=1$.


Your item #$3$ attempt can succeed by using the alternate form of
$$n = \prod_{i=1}^{d}p_i^{r_i}, \;\; \varphi(n) = \prod_{i=1}^{d}(p_i - 1)p_i^{r_i-1}, \;\; r_i \ge 1\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$
Consider the list of all of the primes $p_i$, in increasing order, which are factors of $a$, $b$ and/or $c$. If there are $d$ primes in that list, we then have
$$a = \prod_{i=1}^{d}p_i^{r_i}, \;\; b = \prod_{i=1}^{d}p_i^{s_i}, \;\; c = \prod_{i=1}^{d}p_i^{t_i} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$
Assume that $a = b = c$ is not true. There then must be at least one index $i$ where $r_i \neq s_i$, $s_i \neq t_i$ and/or $t_i \neq r_i$. Let $j$ be the largest such index. Note that, as indicated in \eqref{eq1A}, only the primes larger than $p_j$ may possibly contribute any additional factors of $p_j$ in the Euler totient function result. Also, from the factors of $p_j$ itself, the exponent of $p_j$ in the Euler totient result is $0$ if the exponent is $0$, else it's one less than the exponent. Let $x$ be the net result of accounting for the number of factors of $p_j$ among $10$, $23$ and the larger prime factors, to then get from the set of provided equations that
$$r_j = u + x, \;\; s_j = v + x, \;\; t_j = w + x \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$
where $u = 0$ if $s_j = 0$, else $u = s_j - 1$. Similarly, $v = 0$ if $t_j = 0$, else $v = t_j - 1$, and $w = 0$ if $r_j = 0$, else $w = r_j - 1$. If $r_j \gt 0$, $s_j \gt 0$ and $t_j \gt 0$, then adding the $3$ equations together gives
$$r_j + s_j + t_j = (s_j - 1) + (t_j - 1) + (r_j - 1) + 3x \;\to\; 0 = -3 + 3x \;\to\; x = 1 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$
Using this in \eqref{eq3A} results in $r_j = s_j = t_j$, which contradicts our assumption. Thus, at least one of the exponents must be $0$, say $r_j = 0$, so then $w = 0$ as well. From \eqref{eq3A}, we then get $t_j = x$, so $x \ge 0$. From $r_j = u + x$, since $u \ge 0$, this means we must have $u = 0$ and $x = 0$, so $t_j = 0$. Thus, we have $v = 0$, so $s_j = v + x = 0$ also. Note this actually means that $p_j$ shouldn't even be included in the list since $p_j$ is not a factor of $a$, $b$ and/or $c$. This also contradicts the assumption that the prime exponents are not all the same. Similarly, a contradiction will also occur if $s_j = 0$ or $t_j = 0$ instead.
Since all cases have been covered, this shows there can't be any largest prime factor with a different exponent, so all of the prime exponents must be the same, i.e., we get
$$a = b = c \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Note the above solution method doesn't depend on the specific problem factors of $10$ or $23$. Thus, it can also be used with the general case of
$$ka = m\varphi(b), \;\; kb = m\varphi(c), \;\; kc = m\varphi(a) \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$
for any positive integers $k$ and $m$, to get that the positive integer solutions, if any, of $a$, $b$ and $c$ must satisfy $a = b = c$. Note that for the problem specific values of $k = 10$ and $m = 23$, as indicated in Brian's answer, the variable values are $2^{q_1}11^{q_2}23^{q_3}$ for any positive integers $q_1$, $q_2$ and $q_3$.
